# Rails form using GET method regardless of what is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an HTML form intended to be used for password resetting. Its method is `PATCH` and it should be hitting the `update` method of the `PasswordResetController`. However, on submission, it is always make a `GET` request, regardless of the `method` specified. I can type method=`ANYTHINGHERE` and it always makes a `GET` request.

My form is simple:

```
  <form class="group" action="<%= password_reset_url %>" method="PATCH">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">

    <input type="password" class="password-login" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password">
    <input type="password" class="password-login" name="new_password_verify" placeholder="New Password Confirmation">
    <button class="login-button">Reset Password</button>

  </form>
```

My routes seem to be in order:

```
password_reset_index   POST   /password_reset(.:format)          password_reset#create
new_password_reset     GET    /password_reset/new(.:format)      password_reset#new
edit_password_reset    GET    /password_reset/:id/edit(.:format) password_reset#edit
password_reset         PATCH  /password_reset/:id(.:format)      password_reset#update
                       PUT    /password_reset/:id(.:format)      password_reset#update
```

defined as `resources :password_reset, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]`

And my controller:

```
class PasswordResetController < ApplicationController

    new, edit, create....etc.

    def update
      user = ...
    end

end
```

Create, new, and edit all work perfectly fine, but it's not even getting into the update method when submitting the form. I just get `No route matches [GET] "/password_reset/longTokenString`. Any ideas? I feel like I've exhausted my options here.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476631/rails-post-method-redirecting-to-edit-action-rather-than-create) as the token string is being properly generated. The token string is also used as the id in the `/password_reset/:id/edit` route, and is working fine there as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rails strategy here is the clear explanation if what is the difference between the **PUT** and **PATCH** methods.

If you are coming from a previous version of Rails, you may be wondering why the update action of a RESTful route is mapped to the HTTP verb PATCH instead of PUT. In the HTTP standards document RFC 57892, it outlines that a PUT request to a given resource is meant to completely replace it on the origin server. However, when updating a resource in Rails, rarely, if ever, do you replace an entire resource when performing an update. For example, when updating an Active Record model, Rails sets the attribute updated_at timestamp, not the requesting client.

To follow better HTTP semantics, Rails will be using the HTTP verb PATCH for updates. PATCH allows for both full and partial updates of a resource, and is more suited to how Rails updates resources.If you are upgrading an existing Rails application, the HTTP verb PUT will still map to the update action in
RESTful routes, but it’s recommended to use PATCH moving forward.

> I am going to explain how the User Edit option works in rails.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
 def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

The corresponding user edit view

**app/views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Looking at the HTML source

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1" class="edit_user"
      id="edit_user_1" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

**Note:** Note here the hidden input field:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
```

> Form the Documentation:

```
method: (:get|:post|:patch|:put|:delete)
```

"In the options hash. If the verb is not GET or POST, which are natively supported by HTML forms, the form will be set to POST and a hidden input called _method will carry the intended verb for the server to interpret."

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Hope so my explanation would be clear for understanding the concept. Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. Sometimes it's hard to see the forest through the trees. I actually knew this already but have just been doing so many AJAX patch calls lately that it didn't even enter my mind. Sometimes you get in a routine and basic concepts go out the window. Time to go refresh.... Thanks Naresh!

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML standard, you can not add put as method for form. The only valid values for the method attribute are get and post. `<form method="put">` is invalid HTML and will be treated like `<form>`, i.e. send a GET request.

**You can also write form code by using rails form tag.**

Answer (score 0):

Some points to remember---

1. if you are making use of [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper) tag,you dont have to worry about anything else because rails itself uses its [Record identification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#highlighter_837712) to handle create(POST),new(GET) and update(UPDATE/PATCH) actions.
2. if you are not using form_for tag uniformly,which is your case,you must match the url exactly,**So you need to pass the id too**.

example:-

```
 <form class="group" action="<%= password_reset_url(@your_model.id) %>" method="PATCH">
```

HOPE IT HELPS :)